# Existence and uniqueness for initial value problem with $y'=1/(1+|y|)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem to solve and am not certain of whether my attempt at the solution
is correct.

**Problem description:**
Given an IVP $\dot{y} = \frac{1}{1+|y|},y(0)=y_0\in\mathbb{R}\forall t>0$ 
Check existence and uniqueness of solutions (local and global).

**Attempt at solution**
The first thing that comes to mind when hearing EE is the Theorem of Picard, which states, that given
an ODE $x'=f(t,x(t)$ the function $f$ is continuous w.r.t. $t$ and Lipschitz-Continuous w.r.t. $x$ in
a domain $U \subset \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, where $(t_0,x_0)\in U, x(t_0)=x_0$ being the initial condition.
Then there exists an interval $I=[t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon]$ s.t. there exists a unique solution to the IVP
$x'(t)=f(t,x(t)),x(t_0)=x_0$.

Now I have $f(t,y(t))=f(y(t))$ and thus an autonomous ODE. Following holds:
$||f(y(t))||_\infty \leq 1\quad\forall t\in I$ where $I$ is any interval. Generally $f$ is continuous $\forall t$

Now let $y,z$ be solutions of the ODE, then:
$||f(y)-f(z)||=||\frac{|z|-|y|}{(1+|y|)(1+|z|)}||=(*)$

Now **assuming** $y(t),z(t)\lessgtr 0$ I can certainly get:
$(*) \leq \frac{max_I |z(t) -y(t)|}{min_I |(1+|y(t)|)(1+|z(t)|)|}\leq max_I |z(t) -y(t)| = ||z-y||$
where in the first inequality I use $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$.

Thus I have obtained a Lipschitz-constant and can use Picard's theorem to assert, that
for any $y_0\neq 0$ there exists a unique solution to the IVP.
My problem is, that in the equation above I have used the reverse triangle inequality to obtain the
needed inequality for the L-constant. But if, say, $z(t)>0,y(t)<0$ then I get $||y+z||$ which does not help.

On the other hand, if I look at $f(y(t))$, then it is obvious, that $y(t)$ is increasing for all $t$ ($\dot{y}=f(y(t))\geq 0$)
From this I would deduce, that $y(t)$ is unique given $y(0)=y_0$, globally.

**Question:**
What am I missing to check (global)existence and uniqueness and what (if any) errors are present in the argumentation
above.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You have $$\bigl\lvert \lvert a\rvert - \lvert b\rvert\bigr\rvert \leqslant \lvert a-b\rvert.$$ Always. If $a$ and $b$ are real and have the same sign, you have equality, if they have opposite sign, you have a strict inequality. Anyway you have $\lvert f(a) - f(b)\rvert \leqslant \lvert a-b\rvert$.

Comment: I think that was me being stupid. I've been appending $-$ where it should not be.  So now with the reverse triangle inequality I have a Lipschitz-continuity with $L=1$ on any domain $U=[a,b]\times\mathbb{R}$, thus global existence and uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check the Lipschitz condition of $F(y)=1/(1+|y|)$ is to use the derivative $F'(y)$. Granted, it does not exist at $0$. But since $F$ is even, we have 
$$F(a)-F(b) = F(|a|)-F(|b|)$$
which reduces the consideration to nonnegative arguments. And there the mean value theorem only requires differentiability on $(0,\infty)$.

Since $|F'(y)|=1 /(1+y)^2\le 1$ for $y>0$, the function is  Lipschitz with $L=1$. Global existence and uniqueness follow from the Picard theorem.